# Is there any way to get notified about the internal exceptions thrown by Sql Server2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to know , If I can catch all errors occurred in my database and log it to some user defined table.

**Reason:**

Why I am as so is that, I have web-app running with `Sql2005` as backend. Web app is developed using `Linq2Sql`. It was developed on `2008R2` where as deployed over `Sql2005` on a `Shared Hosting environment`.

I am continuously getting `datetime datatype` error, as in 2008 i have used `date datatype`.

So, what I want is to catch any similar exceptions internally , occurred anywhere in my database and log it to my custom table with fields

**Requirements**

1. Table Name from where the exception has been thrown
2. Name of Procedure, in case if I use it in future
3. Exception message
4. Date time of occurrence

**Please Note**

I dont want to write tablewise exception handling procedures. I want some generic way to get all exceptions, as same as we handle errors in ASP.Net , Global.asax.

**Exception I am getting**

`The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'date'.`

based on above exception, I am not sure which table is throwing this exception. So I want a stored procedure to catch the detail and save to my custom table.

Comment: It would be helpful to actually show an example of the errors you're getting, and clarify if you want to catch them in your stored procedures or in your ASP.NET code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors aren't *internal* to SQL server.  It's probably not even SQL that's giving it to you but rather the db drivers.

If you are using stored procedures, then SQL server would have prevented those s'procs from even being created with the unsupported data type usage.

Considering you are using LINQ, my guess is that LINQ itself is throwing the problem and you'll need to use your regular exception handling around database calls to find it.

Of course, a better path, would be to regenerate your model and/or do a code analysis to locate all references to invalid data types.  Or, even better, switch to a host that is somewhat up to date with their version of SQL server.  There have been a lot of security and performance improvements since then.